# Gradle XJC generate equals and hashCode methods

Tags: java, gradle, jaxb, xjc

The project has a gradle module to build JAX2B classes.
The XJC configuration already uses annotations:

```
    bindingFiles = project.files("$projectDir/src/main/resources/binding.xjb",
      "$projectDir/src/main/resources/annotations.xjb")
    // Needed to execute custom annotations
    options.add("-Xannotate")
}
```

I thought I could add options to get `equals()` and `hashCode()`

```
xjc {
    bindingFiles = project.files("$projectDir/src/main/resources/binding.xjb",
      "$projectDir/src/main/resources/annotations.xjb")
    options.addAll("-Xannotate", "-Xequals", "-XhashCode")
}
```

The methods are not on the class and there are no errors or warnings in the build log.
How do I generate those methods?

PS: Here are the build file dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":xxx:xxx-api"))
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.11.2")
    xjcPlugins("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.11.2")
    xjcPlugins("org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-annotate:1.1.0")
}
```

**UPDATED**

Thanks to @thokuest for spotting a missing dependency.

The project has a gradle module to build JAX2B classes, but I'm getting build errors adding the "-Xequals" option:

```
build/generated/sources/xjc/java/org/pen/ProductOutputType.java:16: error: package org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.locator.util does not exist
import org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.locator.util.LocatorUtils;
                                           ^
build/generated/sources/xjc/java/org/pen/ProductOutputType.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
public class ProductOutputType implements Equals2
                                         ^
```

I've created a minimum example as a gist -- **[build.gradle.kts](https://gist.github.com/ahoffer/12a25c23f919f7b235d5a611a4971154)**

Answer (score 2):

`equals()` and `hashCode()` are contributed by the [jaxb2-basics](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics) plugin.

```
xjcPlugins 'org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics:1.11.1'
```

According to the project's [wiki](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki/Using-JAXB2-Basics-Plugins#using-jaxb-plugins-with-maven), there's a runtime dependency to `org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-runtime:1.11.1` that you would need to add as well.

**Update**

Dependency `org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-runtime:1.11.1` must be in scope `implementation` as otherwise a build error as described in the question occurs.

Comment: Thanks. I missed that. I added it and got a little further. I'll update the question.

Comment: @ahoffer answer updated. You need to add `org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-runtime:1.11.1` to scope `implementation`.